# c# and ffpmeg command line trouble

Tags: c#, php, ffmpeg

I have a php code that calls ffmpeg from the windows command line (because I run apache locally) with:

```
//ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -r 20 output.gif
        echo exec('C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i videos/file.avi -r 10  -s 450x230 videos/file.gif');
```

And it works fine! Now I wrote a C# program and I try to do the same thing with:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start
```

but it fails.

Question: How do I execute the same command from the PHP code but from inside a C# code?

Comment: "from the windows command line (because I run apache locally)" - please elaborate how those two statements are related. Exactly how is the php script started and how do you execute the .net app?

Comment: I have a php script that I run on my windows machine via browser. I have a local apache server installed. And the php script converts via ffmpeg well when I call the script voer browser. Now I try to do the same command from C#.

Comment: the php code and .net are not connected. That maybe confused you. I just want the command line for ffmpeg that works in PHP to work in C# too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Process process = Process.Start(
    new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe",
        Arguments = "-i videos/file.avi -r 10  -s 450x230 videos/file.gif",
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    }
);
process.WaitForExit();
```

If it fails an exception will be raised, e.g. 
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception with HResult=-2147467259 if the executable wasn't found.